# how to enable user interaction on animated objects?

Tags: ios, animation, swift, uiscrollview

For some reason animated cell disable interaction over them, which makes my collection view scrolling useless. If I put my hand in between two cells, the scrolling works, so the animation somehow enters disables touch interaction over them. The animation goes on forever:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2,
    delay: 0.0,
    options: UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat,
    animations: {
        cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMake(1.0, 0.0, skew, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    },
    completion: nil);
```

How can I work around this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Try adding `UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction` flag ?

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know this flag existed